# MySql offset query not working

Tags: mysql, sql, offset

I have MySql Workbench 6.2CE (hope this helps..)
And I'm trying to an offset query like this :

```
SELECT id FROM nameTable OFFSET 10 ROWS;
```

But it give me a syntax error on the 10 : is not a valid input in this position.
Anyone knows the problem ?Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax is wrong and its

```
select * from table order by someid
[LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}]
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Note that limit without order by is having no meaning.

```
SELECT id FROM nameTable order by id limit 10 OFFSET 10
```

Comment: ow i see, then if i want to use `OFFSET`, i should use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` too, right ?

Comment: Well mysql does not preserve ordered data while returning data , so its better to use order by clause for a meaning full result. You may use different version of limit something as `limit 0,10` or `limit 10 offset 0` are same.